# Is it Possiable to call to previous increments of a variable?

Tags: javascript, logic, terminology

for example lets say i have a loop that is doing basic counting, while the variable is less than 16 the loop will run and at the end of the loop you add 2 to the variable and add one to a "count" variable

what i want to know is if its possible to callback to any of the previous variables for either variable for example can i count all the times count % 2 === 0?

im not quite sure if once a variable makes any kind of change if all previous versions of that variable are gone

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gojoxm

```
var two = 0;
var count = 0;
while ( two < 16) {
  two += 2;
  count++;
};

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, then no, you cannot. When you assign a new value to a variable, the previous value is lost.

You have to either run this loop again or store intermediate values in an array:

```
var values = [];
var two = 0;

while (two < 16) {
    two += 2;
    values.push(two);
}

console.log(values.length); // the same result
```

Then, you will always be able to do whatever you want with these values.
For example, you can check if there were any odd values:

```
var anyOddNumbers = values.some(function(x) { return x % 2 === 1; }); // false
```